# Street-Level Routing (SLR) Isn't Registered - Field Service

Tags: fieldservice, remote-site-settings

I'm developing an app with Field Service on a Sandbox. I'm **trying to enable SLR**. I just ran the `Health Check` of Field Service Admin, and the result is:
[image]

I press the Register button that appears on `Field Service Settings/Optimization/Routing` to the right of *'Register to the Street-Level Routing'* service. However, when the page refreshes, I run the test again and encounter the same error. The button reappears.

What can I do to solve this problem?